# How to connect images to an object which hasn't yet been created?

Tags: symfony

I'm working with PHP and Symfony where I have a `ForumPost` and a `ForumPostImage` entity, and they both work fine separately.

I have a "Create Post" page with three fields a Submit button.

The first two fields are related to the `ForumPost` entity: `title`, `content` and then the Submit button.

The third field is a `Dropzone field` (dropzone.dev) where the user can upload images by drag and drop - the images are uploaded instantly (without hitting the Submit button) as
`ForumPostImage` objects.

It all works - when clicking the Submit button the post is created and the images have already been uploaded.

The issue is: How do I connect each `ForumPostImage` object to the `ForumPost` object? I was thinking about doing something like `$forumPostImage->setForumPost($forumPost)`, but this doesn't really work while being on the Create Post page, right? I mean, the `ForumPost` hasn't even been created, so *how* and *when* should I use this method `setForumPost(...)`?

```
// Route: Create post

    #[Route('/create', name: 'app_forum_newpost')]
    public function new(EntityManagerInterface $entityManager, Request $request, ForumCategoryRepository $forumCategoryRepository)
    {
        $this->denyAccessUnlessGranted('ROLE_USER');

        $form = $this->createForm(ForumPostFormType::class);
        $form->handleRequest($request);

        if($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {
            /** @var ForumPost $forumPost */
            $forumPost = $form->getData();

            $categoryId = $request->request->get('categoryId');

            $forumPost->setCategory($forumCategoryRepository->findOneBy(['id' => $categoryId]));
            $forumPost->setCreatedBy($this->getUser());
            $forumPost->setUpdatedBy($this->getUser());
            $forumPost->setLastActivityAt(new \DateTime());
            $forumPost->setLastActivityBy($this->getUser());

            $entityManager->persist($forumPost);
            $entityManager->flush();

            return $this->redirectToRoute('app_forum_viewpost', [
                'slug' => $forumPost->getSlug(),
                'post' => $forumPost,
            ]);
        }
        return $this->render('forum/new.html.twig', [
            'form' => $form->createView(),
            'headline' => 'Create post',
        ]);
    }
```

```
// Route: Upload image through Dropzone

    #[Route('/upload-image', name: 'app_forum_upload_image', methods: ['POST'])]
    public function uploadImage(EntityManagerInterface $entityManager, Request $request, SluggerInterface $slugger)
    {
        /** @var UploadedFile $image */
        $image = $request->files->get('file');

        $targetDirectory = $this->getParameter('forum_directory');

        $fileUploader = new FileUploader($targetDirectory, $slugger);

        $newFilename = $fileUploader->upload($image);

        $forumPostImage = new ForumPostImage();
        $forumPostImage->setOriginalFilename(pathinfo($image->getClientOriginalName(), PATHINFO_FILENAME));
        $forumPostImage->setFilename($newFilename);
        
        // not used: $forumPostImage->setForumPost($forumPost);

        $entityManager->persist($forumPostImage);
        $entityManager->flush();

        return $this->redirectToRoute('app_forum_newpost');
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

You can't, you need to first have ForumPost persisted.

1. One way to tackle this is, that you persist the images without ForumPost and return their id's which the frontend will receive after upload. Then, when the user presses submit, you send the images id's together with the 2 fields and then you can attach the images normally in app_forum_newpost.

With this approach, the user can accidentally, or on purpose create images
that are never attached to any ForumPost, maybe you want to use crontab to clear these.

2. Another approach would be to use some kind of draft system for forum posts. This means, that the user always gets a persisted version of the ForumPost or even ForumPostDraft, when they enter the create view. This is much more extendable and usable than the first approach but also much more work. This is likely the way most of the forums and similar systems do this.

If you don't need drafts just yet, then go for the easy option 1) you can always easily go 2) when needed.